# Play Framework 2.0 and Ebean SQL logging

Tags: logging, playframework-2.0, ebean

I want to examine what SQL statements are generated by Ebean to find out why certain exceptions (related to SQL syntax) are occurring in my Play 2.0 application. **Is there a way to log the SQL statements generated by Ebean in Play Framework 2.0?**

In Play 1.x, there is a `jpa.debugSQL` config option, which if set to true, will do exactly this. Does a similar setting for Ebean exist for Play 2.0? The [documentation page about Ebean of Play 2.0](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaEbean) is still a bit scarce.

---

**What I have tried so far:**

I have added these method calls in my controllers and the `onStart` / `onRequest` methods of the Global object, but it doesn't have any effect:

```
Ebean.getServer(null).getAdminLogging().setLogLevel(LogLevel.SQL);
Ebean.getServer(null).getAdminLogging().setDebugGeneratedSql(Play.isDev());
```

I have modified the log levels from `application.conf`, but it didn't help either (even with log level `TRACE`).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Sorry to be late to the party, but I use this in development:

```
db.default.logStatements=true

logger.com.jolbox=DEBUG
```

Add those two lines to the application.conf and you are good to go.

It outputs all the sql statements.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable SQL logging by using the following statement

```
Ebean.getServer(null).getAdminLogging().setDebugGeneratedSql(true);
```

Use this command in the [onRequest](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaInterceptors) interceptor for example

In a next release, you will certainly be able to configure this in the file [ebean.properties](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/156-add-support-for-ebeanproperties).

```
// Tips : use Play.isDev() to log only in dev mode
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion (I added the above statement to both `onStart` and `onRequest` methods in my Global object), but I still do not see any SQL statements in my application's logs.

Comment: I haven't try in Play2.0 final,i will retry soon (RC3 last test). Try to change Log level in the application.conf or in the AdminLogging instance.  Do you use "default" as database source ?

Comment: Yes, "default" datasource. Tried setting the log level in application.conf and AdminLogging instance. A lot of other stuff appear in the logs, but alas, no SQL statements, even with log level `TRACE`.

Comment: 2 questions : try by adding this line directry in your controller, and if it works, are you sure your Global object is well defined ? (there is  a config to set if the global object is not in the root package, symply add a Sysout to see whether it works). I tried with Play 2.0 final yesterday and it works.

Comment: The Global object is ok. I have `Logger.info()` calls in both `onStart` and `onRequest` methods and I can see their output in the console. Even so, I still added it in the controller as well - no effect. So, the Ebean methods must get called, but for some reason, do not work.

Comment: it's weird, i can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get SQL on the spot by using method getGeneratedSQL. Code sample below

```
        Query<PreventionActivity> where = find.where(
            and(
                    and(
                    ge("Age_FROM", age)
                    , or(le("Age_TO", age), eq("Age_TO", 0))
                    )
                    , or(eq("Gender_CD", genderCd), eq("Gender_CD", "*"))
            )
    );

    List<PreventionActivity> list = where.findList();
    Logger.info("sql ");
    Logger.info(where.getGeneratedSql());
```