# PagingList page returning wrong row count in ebean

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am generating a `PagingList` from a table using `RawSql`.

I have two entities, `TableEntry` and `TableEntryAvg`. The latter is performing a `GROUP BY` on the first table to average rows together.

My call looks something like:

```
Query query = Ebean.find(TableEntryAvg.class);

String sql = "SELECT MIN(id) as id,"
   +" AVG(count) as count, AVG(tof) as tof, AVG(ext) as ext," 
   +" AVG(ratio_gfp) as ratio_gfp, AVG(ratio_tof) as ratio_tof, AVG(ratio_ext) as ratio_ext, COUNT(rep) as rep, "
   +"strain, clone_id, plate_id, exp"
   +" FROM table_entry GROUP BY strain, clone_id, exp, plate_id";

RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql)
                  .columnMapping("clone_id", "clone_id")
                  .columnMapping("strain", "strain")
                  .columnMapping("plate_id", "plate_id")
                  .columnMapping("exp", "exp");

PagingList pl = query
                .setRawSql(rawSql)
                .findPagingList(pageSize);
```

Now calling `pl.getTotalRowCount()` gives me a value of 40 which is incorrect. The table on the front end shows I have 55 rows:

Here are some screenshots from the pagination on the front end. My page size is 20 so there are 3 pages.

Page 1

[image: Page 1]

Page 2

[image: Page 2]

Page 3

[image: Page 3]

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Please let me know if I missed any critical information that would help, its hard to include it all in the question.

Thanks

Comment: Is anyone able to help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719601/play-framework-2-0-and-ebean-sql-logging for checking which sql is being generated