# play framework 2.2 : How to define an ebean ManyToMany query

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

I am trying to implement the yabe tutorial from play 1.0 in play 2.0

Currently I am stuck at the tagging functionality: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/guide6

Essentially the problem is this:

I have a Post class, each Post object can have multiple number of tags associated with that class:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
public Set<Tag> tags;
```

I want to write a function which, given an array of tags, will return a list of Posts, if and only if all tags are present in the Post objects.

The unit tests are as follows:

```
    @Test
public void testTags() {
    // Create a new user and save it
    SuperUser.setInstance("bob@gmail.com", "secret", "Bob").save();

    SuperUser bob = SuperUser.getInstance();

    // Create a new post
    Post bobPost = new Post(bob, "Hello world","My first post");
    bobPost.save();

    Post anotherBobPost = new Post(bob, "Hello world", "Hop");
    anotherBobPost.save();

    // Well
    assertEquals(0, Post.findTaggedWith("Red").size());

    // Tag it now
    bobPost.tagItWith("Red").tagItWith("Blue").save();
    anotherBobPost.tagItWith("Red").tagItWith("Green").save();

    // Check
    assertEquals(2, Post.findTaggedWith("Red").size());
    assertEquals(1, Post.findTaggedWith("Blue").size());
    assertEquals(1, Post.findTaggedWith("Green").size());

    // Checks for multiple tag params
    assertEquals(1, Post.findTaggedWith("Red", "Blue").size()); //Fail -  Actual: 0
    assertEquals(1, Post.findTaggedWith("Red", "Green").size());
    assertEquals(0, Post.findTaggedWith("Red", "Green", "Blue").size());
    assertEquals(0, Post.findTaggedWith("Green", "Blue").size());

    SuperUser.removeSuperUser();

}
```

My current implementation is as follows:

```
    public static List<Post> findTaggedWith(String... tags) {

    ExpressionList<Post> expAcc = Post.find.fetch("tags").where().conjunction();

    for( String tag : tags){

        expAcc = expAcc.eq("tags.name", tag);

    }

    return expAcc.endJunction().findList();
}
```

I have no idea what to do next, as I am brute forcing this and getting nowhere :(

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: The list returned by function is empty

Answer (score 1):

Try turning EBean SQL logging. Very helpful to see what SQL statements EBean is executing.

See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719601/play-framework-2-0-and-ebean-sql-logging)

Answer (score 0):

You're really close. The problem is in your relationship. What you want in your `Post` class is this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "post")
public Set<Tag> tags;
```

and then in your `Tag` class, add this:

```
@ManyToOne()
public Post post;
```

Depending on how closely your DB schema matches your Model class, you may or may not have to experiment with adding `@JoinColumn` annotations.

This shows Ebean the intended relationship. `One (Post) to Many (Tags)` in the Post Model, `Many (Tags) to One (Post)` in the Tag Model.