# Scala + Ebean: orderBy not working?

Tags: scala, playframework, sql-order-by, ebean

This is a simple situation but for some reason `orderBy` for me hasn't worked.

I have a very simple model class;

```
case class Sale(price: Int, name: String) {
  @Id
  var id: Long = 0
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    var saleDate: DateTime = new DateTime()
}
```

and the companion object;

```
object Sale {
    def find = new Finder[String, Sale](classOf[String], classOf[Sale])
}
```

Then I'm trying to fetch the list of all sale entries and order them using the `saleDate` value;

```
Sale.find
  .where
  ... // some conditions
  .orderBy("saleDate desc")
  .findMap
```

It seems pretty simple and straightforward to me, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know what might the reason be?

Comment: Any chance you can put together a tiny project to test with?

Comment: Try to use `orderBy().desc("saleDate")` instead and enable [SQL queries logging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11956193/1205368) so you can see what actually gets executed.

Comment: @Nate, Salem I've posted the answer. Thanks for looking into this, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a little strange and I've found a solution. Turns out, when you do `.findMap`, and the keys of the resulting `map` are the `id's` of the found entries, `ebean/scala` decides to arrange the keys in order (in my case, ascending), completely ignoring the intended order of the found elements. So to solve this, all I needed to do was to replace `.findMap` with `.findList`.

This does bring us to an interesting possibility – arranging responses without having to do an expensive `orderBy`; just fetch the entries into a `map` with the keys being the ordering parameter. I am currently using that approach and it works perfectly. It is efficient, in fact.