# Play - Deleting a post by id using Ebean permanantly

Tags: java, ebean

I am implementing a delete option for a post! I have got `model` for a post and a `deletePostOnly()` java method for it to delete it PERMANENTLY using ebean `delete()` function.

But the problem is that it is doing nothing and it is not deleting the post.
Following is the picture of the sample post.

[image]

delete post java method

```
public static Result deletePostOnly(Long postId) {

    //check if post can be deleted with this user
    SimplePost post = SimplePost.find.byId(postId);
    if(post == null) {
        return badRequest();
    }

    UserAccount account = Secured.getCurrentUser();
    if(!(post.getPostUserId().equals(account.getId()))) {
        return badRequest();
    }

    try {
        post.delete();        
        post.save();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ok("ok");
}
```

This is the `delete()` function it is calling on

```
public void delete() {
    Ebean.delete(this);
}
```

This is `save()` function

```
@Override
public void save() {
    super.save();
}
```

I have also tried using creating ebean query, but it is very inconsistent (it works sometimes & it doesn't sometimes.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong or may be another different way to delete this post more efficiently? I couldn't think of it!

Any help/suggestions much welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

If you save your bean after having deleted it, you basically recreate it. Leave out the `post.save()` line.

Comment: Then you should take a look on the kind or request you are sending to the database. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719601/play-framework-2-0-and-ebean-sql-logging

Comment: According to the accepted answer, in my **application.conf** file, following are been set:
`db.default.logStatements=false`  
`logger.com.jolbox=DEBUG`

Comment: do you want me to change that `db.default.logStatements=true`? but what difference will it make?

Comment: You will see what kind of requests are sent to the database.