# PlayFrameWork: Ebean delete ERROR

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

In relation to this  [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688030/play-deleting-a-post-by-id-using-ebean-permanantly), I haven't got any help so was thinking to explain it in another way.

So I have a `model` for a posting a wallpost and a delete option to delete it by **@id** (`stream_post_id`)

Following is my model

```
import play.db.ebean.Model;


 @Entity   
 @Table(name="stream_post_simple")
 @SequenceGenerator(name="stream_post_id", sequenceName="stream_post_stream_post_id_seq", allocationSize=1)

public class SimplePost extends Model implements Post, Broadcastable, PostSerialiser {
    @Id
    @Column(name="stream_post_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="stream_post_id")
    protected Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name="post")
    protected String post;

    @Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Calendar posted = Calendar.getInstance();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="account_id")
    @Column(name="account_id")
    protected Account account;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="poster_id")
    @Column(name="poster_id")
    protected Account poster;
```

Following is my delete method

```
public static Result deletePostOnly(Long postId) {

    //check if post can be deleted with this user
    SimplePost post = SimplePost.find.byId(postId);
    if(post == null) {
        return badRequest();
    }

    UserAccount account = Secured.getCurrentUser();
    if(!(post.getPostUserId().equals(account.getId()))) {
        return badRequest();
    }

    try {
       post.delete();   //ebean delete     
       post.save();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }

 return ok("ok");
}
```

BUT This is not working and giving me an **error** as:

```
ERROR Executing DML bindlog[]error [No value specified for parameter 5.]
```

I don't know where I am going wrong.
Any help is much appreciated thanks

Comment: Why are you deleting it and trying to save it right after?

Comment: In order to save the changes of delete() function. I have also tried it getting rid of save() but its not working!